# Enable a Button when Progress bar has Loaded Completely. In android studio

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

When progress bar is loading enable button click in android studio using java .

When progress bar is loading button click enable .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, define max progress a progress bar can gain, using XML or programmatically.

In XML,

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"/>
```

Assuming, You will be using CountDownTimer, to track the progress, when the progress will hit the max [May use If condition inside the onTick() or onFinish() can do the job],and then you may enable the button.

```
progress_bar.setProgress(100); //setMax()
myButton.setEnabled(true);
```